# Find a sequence of consecutive rows with the same value in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, sequence, window-functions

I have a dataframe ordered by date. Each row contains a "flag" column (values are 1 or 0). I want to find the sequences of 3 (or more) consecutive rows with the "flag" value equal to 1. The objective is to reset the "flag" value to 0 if it is not part of a 3 or more consecutive elements sequence with the :flag" being 1.

This is an example of the data:

| date | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 |
| 02-01-2022 | 1 |
| 03-01-2022 | 1 |
| 04-01-2022 | 1 |
| 05-01-2022 | 0 |
| 06-01-2022 | 0 |
| 07-01-2022 | 1 |
| 08-01-2022 | 1 |
| 09-01-2022 | 0 |
| 10-01-2022 | 1 |

We have to keep value 1 only for the first 4 rows, as they constitute a sequence of four rows (more than 3) with a 1 in the flag. The desired output should be:

| date | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 |
| 02-01-2022 | 1 |
| 03-01-2022 | 1 |
| 04-01-2022 | 1 |
| 05-01-2022 | 0 |
| 06-01-2022 | 0 |
| 07-01-2022 | 0 |
| 08-01-2022 | 0 |
| 09-01-2022 | 0 |
| 10-01-2022 | 0 |

I thought that maybe it makes sense to use the `lag` function based on the previous element but not sure about how efficient it is in PySpark.

Comment: does this dataframe have any groups, like an ID or name?

Comment: the one I'll work with yes, it has a name field that we should use to consider only consecutive appearances only for that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use several window functions. Counting flags in 3 different windows: `-2:0`, `-1:1`, `0:-2`. If the `sum` of at least one from these is `3`, then you have 3 consecutive 1's.

In the following script I assumed tat your dates are stored in the *string* data type, so I have used a column expression `date` to read true dates from strings. If your dates are not in string format, you should not use that line.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('01-01-2022', 1),
     ('02-01-2022', 1),
     ('03-01-2022', 1),
     ('04-01-2022', 1),
     ('05-01-2022', 0),
     ('06-01-2022', 0),
     ('07-01-2022', 1),
     ('08-01-2022', 1),
     ('09-01-2022', 0),
     ('10-01-2022', 1)],
    ['date', 'flag'])
```

Script:

```py
date = F.to_date('date', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
cond1 = F.sum('flag').over(W.orderBy(date).rowsBetween(-2, 0)) == 3
cond2 = F.sum('flag').over(W.orderBy(date).rowsBetween(-1, 1)) == 3
cond3 = F.sum('flag').over(W.orderBy(date).rowsBetween(0, 2)) == 3
df = df.withColumn('flag', (cond1 | cond2 | cond3).cast('long'))

df.show()
# +----------+----+
# |      date|flag|
# +----------+----+
# |01-01-2022|   1|
# |02-01-2022|   1|
# |03-01-2022|   1|
# |04-01-2022|   1|
# |05-01-2022|   0|
# |06-01-2022|   0|
# |07-01-2022|   0|
# |08-01-2022|   0|
# |09-01-2022|   0|
# |10-01-2022|   0|
# +----------+----+
```

Comment: This worked! In order to generalize it for any number of elements in a row I did:

`conds_list = [F.sum('flag').over(Window.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-N +1 + i, i)) == N for i in range(0, N)]

cond = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, conds_list)

df = df.withColumn('flag', cond.cast('long'))
`

Comment: That's a clever approach :) I was thinking about `reduce`, but didn't want to complicate the simple answer. It's cool that you did it yourself.